# How do I access the lan side of a l2tp server

Tags: router, vpn, l2tp

I am working remotely from a small business which has a dreytek router.  At home I have a tplink ER605

I have successfully created a L2TP preshared key tunnel from the tplink device (as L2TP client) to the small business office with the a lan to lan dial-in only tunnel

I run on 192.168.x.0/24 subnet at home and the small business runs on 192.68.y.0/24 subnet, where there are number of web and ssh servers.  I can easily browse these web sites and ssh into any of the devices EXCEPT one.

The router itself is on 192.168.y.1 and I cannot access it, which I need to do to edit the router configuration.

However in this office there is also a Dial VPN tunnel using PPTP and I can connect to it solely from a windows machine that I have.  But on this machine I can access the routers web interface, so I can do it that way.

Is there an inherent limitation of the l2tp vpn tunnel that is not there with the others?

The big problem I have is that I have another tunnel into a different office on 192.168.z.0/24, same situation I can access devices apart from the router.  However on this one there is no additional dial in VPN connections and I have misconfigured something on the router. Is there anything I can do other than physically visit the site.